# Connected views from xib file not showing and alwasy nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, viewcontroller

My views are connected to my ViewContoller swift file, the file owner's ok, but it's not working for me. The views aren't appear and they are nils. I upload some picture to more informations. I tried everything. Clean project, reload xcode, delete delivered data, delete emualtor data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you load, initialize your ViewController? You need to load it from StoryBoard.
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryBoardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewControllerName") as? UIViewController

Comment: I load it with navigation controller.             self.navigationController.pushViewController(screen, animated: animated)
All the other views loaded. Which files i created after friday dont work.

Comment: Do I understand correctly? 
Test3View.xib is UIViewController? And it owns the view viwka?
In your answer navigationController.pushViewController(screen, animated: animated)
"screen" is Test3View.xib?

Comment: Test3.swift is the viewController and the screen is the viewController class.

Comment: @HeyJoe - there are various different approaches to using xib files and how to load and use them. You need to provide more information on what you are doing. Review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @HeyJoe -  how do you load the "screen". You need to load it from storyboard as in my example in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are initializing the view controller but not loading it from a storyboard. You could try adding an extension to UIViewController for easy loading:

```
extension UIViewController {
    class func loadFromNib<T: UIViewController>() -> T {
         return T(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}

let vc : Test3 = Test3.loadFromNib()
navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: animated)
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html